# how to return a value from a javascript function with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a small javascript function and I am using ajax on it.

```
     function checklogin() {

     var unp = $("#input-36").val();
     var pwp = $("#input-35").val();

     $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo site_url()."/login/main"?>',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
             un: unp,
             pw: pwp
         },
         success: function(data) {
             document.getElementById("errorid").innerHTML = data;
         },
         error: function(err, req) {
             alert("Your browser broke!");
         }
     });
     return false;
 }
```

What I want is: I want to return false only if there are some values in my data variable. Otherwise I want to return true.

But I can't return false inside this function:

```
success: function(data) {
             document.getElementById("errorid").innerHTML = data;
         },
```

So how should I do that?

Comment: Don't get it. Please update your answer.

Comment: Success and error are callbacks. They are called after post call result. They are asynchronous.. You can't return true or false.

Comment: Use a temporary variable to store the data from the ajax call, then use a simple if statement after the ajax call to check for your 'values' and return false.

Comment: You are storing the value of `data` after getting the response, so why can't you check if `document.getElementById("errorid").innerHTML` is empty or no and then return necessary value?

Comment: return json response by login/main method and console.log(data).